# How to remove the border in axis with pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

As illustrated in the circle in the image, there's a little gap between the **0** and the border. How can I remove that little gap?

[image: pgfplot]

## MWE

Sample code to generate above plot

```
% in preamble
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
 x,y
 0.01,0.9583333333
 0.02,0.8125
 %...100 in total...
\end{filecontents*}

% in document
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{legend style={font=\tiny}}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={Recall},
      xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1},
      ylabel={Precision},
      ytick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1},
      legend cell align=left,
      legend pos=north east]

    \addplot[c1, thin, mark=square, mark repeat=5] table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

    \addlegendentry{x-y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{plot}\label{fig:plot}
\end{figure}
```

## Update:

Here's what I expected by using Matlab. Note at the bottom left corner, there's one **0** label which is shared by both x and y axis.

[image]

Comment: `enlarge x limits=false` is I think what you are looking for. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: exactly :). Please convert this to an answer.

Comment: one problem...it also removed the **0** label

Comment: If that's the case we need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), because it doesn't do that with some simple code I started setting up to write an answer.

Comment: I added my sample code. Hope it helps.

Comment: @davidshen84 The Matlab plot you posted doesn't actually have a shared 0 label for both axes: the x-axis goes from 0 to 1, but the y-axis seems to go from 0.1 to 1, not from 0.

Comment: Put `xmin=0` as you don't have dtata for `x=0`.

Comment: @HarishKumar, very good observation :) Thanks. Now I am happy with my chart.

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you want to answer this?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I will leave it to Paul Gessler.

Comment: @PaulGessler Want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of suggestions in the comments led to the solution.

By default, `pgfplots` will slightly enlarge the plot viewport when it automatically detects axis limits based on the plot data. The key settings `enlargelimits=false` or `enlarge x limits=false` may be used to prevent this for all axes or individual axes, respectively.

However, in this case, the bounds of the plotted data do not match the desired axis limits. Here, setting the axis limits (`xmin=0`, etc.) explicitly gives the desired result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
 x,y
 0.01,0.9583333333
 0.02,0.8125
 %...100 in total...
 0.99,0.1875
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  enlarge x limits=false,
  xlabel={Recall},
  xmin=0,xmax=1,
  xtick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1},
  ylabel={Precision},
  ymin=0.1,ymax=1,
  ytick={0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1},
]
  \addplot table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \addlegendentry{x-y};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) This works also without to manually set `xtick` and `ytick`, however in this case the tick are at 0, 0.2, ..., 1.